# need help for setting progressbars for webview clicks

Tags: android, progress-bar, webview

friend's
         I wanna need to know how to set progressbars for webview,when i click submenus or links from that webpage.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set WebChromeClient and override onProgressChanged.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
    //do something with progress
  }
});